# YQL console not working

Tags: jquery, yql

I had built a stock quotes widget but now find that it no longer works. Is something up with Yahoo? Here is a link to the YQL query which did and should work.

http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20where%20symbol%20in%20%28%22YHOO%22%2C%22AAPL%22%2C%22GOOG%22%2C%22MSFT%22%29%0A%09%09&env=http%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltables.env

Many thanks,
C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is http://datatables.org is down at the moment, which YQL uses to store its open data table definitions.

Comment: Thanks for that Dan! Hopefully back up soon.